# configure: error: cannot find libz

Tags: mesos, linux-mint

Building Mesos 1.3.0 from sources on linux-mint release 18.2 I get the following message:

```
configure: error: cannot find libz
```

When I try to search packages starts with libz* I get many packages names starting with libz. Which one is the right package I should install it?

Answer (score 7):

Try installing [`zlib1g-dev`](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/zlib1g-dev). It's listed in [the documentation](http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/)

---

> [Linux Mint 18.2 is based on Ubuntu 16.04.](https://www.linuxmint.com/rel_sonya_cinnamon.php)

So, you should follow instructions for Ubuntu
16.04.

```
 # Update the packages.
 $ sudo apt-get update

 # Install a few utility tools.
 $ sudo apt-get install -y tar wget git

 # Install the latest OpenJDK.
 $ sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk

 # Install autotools (Only necessary if building from git repository).
 $ sudo apt-get install -y autoconf libtool

 # Install other Mesos dependencies.
 $ sudo apt-get -y install build-essential python-dev python-six python-virtualenv libcurl4-nss-dev libsasl2-dev libsasl2-modules maven libapr1-dev libsvn-dev zlib1g-dev
```